# VBA - Userform name to cell value

Tags: vba, userform

help me:
I have 2 UserForms: `UF123` and `UF456`
I want call name from `Sheet6.Cells(11, 12)` = `UF123` or `UF456` : `UForm = Sheet6.Cells(11, 12).Value`
I want set `UserForms(UForm).ComboBox5.Value = abc`
but it not run.

```
Dim UForm As String 
UForm = Sheet6.Cells(11, 12).Value           
UserForms(UForm).ComboBox5.Value = 5
```

Comment: *"but it not run."* is no useful error description. Please [edit] your question and add which errors you get and in which line. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: I am using the same module for multiple userforms. I want to assign the name of the userform I use to the command in the module. It is the same as above.

Comment: That doesn't help much, your question is still unclear. Please [edit] your question and add which errors you get and in which line. Also please ask a question other than *"Can help me?"*

Comment: I have 2 UserForms: UF123 and UF456. I want to enter the name of USERFORM ( UF123 or UF456) from cell Sheet6.Cells (11, 12) . I want to assign value 5 to the textbox5 of the userform I just entered into Sheet6.Cells (11, 12) . My code wrong UserForms(UForm).ComboBox5.Value = 5. there's a problem with my command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this cannot work as `UserForms` only contains userforms that are actually shown at the moment.

You can easily test this by

```
Debug.Print VBA.UserForms.Count
```

it will show `0` if no userform is shown and if you do

```
UF123.Show vbModeless
Debug.Print VBA.UserForms.Count
```

it will show `1`.

Also you cannot access it by its name using `UserForms("UF123")` this is not supported.
So there is only a workaround:

```
Dim UForm As Object

Select Case Sheet6.Cells(11, 12).Value
    Case "UF123"
        Set UForm = New UF123
        
    Case "UF456"
        Set UForm = New UF456
        
    Case Else
        MsgBox "not found"
End Select

UForm.ComboBox5.Value = 5
UForm.Show

Set UForm = Nothing
```

Comment: great. Thank you.